# Unable to use Android platform's MediaCodec class in "surface input" mode

Tags: android, c++, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to write a simple video encoder that uses the Android platform's [`MediaCodec`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/media/libstagefright/include/media/stagefright/MediaCodec.h) class in "surface input" mode.

These are the steps I'm following (supporting code left out for the sake of brevity):

```
mediaCodec = MediaCodec::CreateByType(looper, "video/avc", true);
mediaCodec->configure(config, NULL, NULL, CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
mediaCodec->createInputSurface(&inputSurface);
mediaCodec->start();
```

Following this, I'm trying to dequeue a buffer from the created input surface (which is an [`IGraphiBufferProducer`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/include/gui/IGraphicBufferProducer.h) interface object), but it fails with the [`NO_INIT`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/include/gui/IGraphicBufferProducer.h#174) error:

```
inputSurface->dequeueBuffer(&slot, &fence, w, h, format, 0);
```

The error message in the ADB log is:

```
BufferQueueProducer: [GraphicBufferSource] dequeueBuffer: BufferQueue has no connected producer
```

Any idea why the buffer queue has no connected producer? I would assume that the `MediaCodec` class would handle the creation of the buffer queue as well as the connection of the producer and consumers to the queue.

I'm using Android API level 26 (7.1.2). I'm using the platform-level libs because my use case requires access to `GraphicBuffer` objects.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The general idea is to:

- Dequeue buffers from the input surface & fill them.
- Queue the filled buffers back to the input surface (which would presumably trigger the media codec (video encoder) instance that the surface belongs
  to).
- Dequeue output buffers (containing raw H.264 bitstream data) from the media codec instance, and write it to file.
- Release output buffers back to the media codec instance.

Answer (score 0):

From [`IGraphiBufferProducer`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/include/gui/IGraphicBufferProducer.h) documentation:

```
// * NO_INIT - the buffer queue has been abandoned or the producer is not
//             connected.
```

I guess that the part that is missing in your code is this "connect".

[`IGraphiBufferProducer`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/include/gui/IGraphicBufferProducer.h) has such a method, are you using it?